# Quantum computing records (storage times)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, temperature, quantum-computer

Long storage times for qubits will be integral in the construction of a scalable quantum computer. This leads me to ask the current state of affairs in our ability to store qubits. Namely, what is the **record** storage time for a qubit at **any** temperature?

Upon searching for the record storage time I found the following result at **room** temperature: https://www.sciencemag.org/content/342/6160/830

I'd be quite surprised if cooling the system didn't provide an increase in storage time. However, the costs of cooling might outweigh the gain in storage time. Thus, I am interested in how the storage time depends upon temperature.